# Print Dataframe with for and show data and name of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a row-by-row print of a Dataframe with pandas.

the dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

and if do print(df) show this

```
   id   name   stock  
0   1   Fruit    8
1   2   Meet    10
2   3   Fish    30
3   4   Cake    20
```

my intention is to make a for and inside something like this

```
for ???? :
print(f"the column {id_column_name} is {id_row} and {name_column_name} {name_row} have {name_column_stock} {stock_row}  ")
```

and print

```
The column id is 1 and name Fruit have stock 8
The column id is 2 and name Meet have stock 10
The column id is 3 and name Fish have stock 30
The column id is 4 and name Cake have stock 20
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Answer (score 0):

One way that I accomplished this is using the following:

```
def f(id_, name, stock, cols):
    print(f"The column {cols[0]} is {id_} and {cols[1]} {name} have {cols[2]} {stock}")

for x, y, z in zip(df['id'], df['name'], df['stock']):
    f(x, y, z, df.columns)
```

I iterated through the zipped columns and applied a function prints out the desired output by taking in that information and the column names.

Output:

```
The column id is 1 and name Fruit have stock 8
The column id is 2 and name Meet have stock 10
The column id is 3 and name Fish have stock 30
The column id is 4 and name Cake have stock 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using df.iterrows():

```
import io
import pandas as pd

string = string = """id name stock
1   Fruit    8
2   Meet    10
3   Fish    30
4   Cake    20
"""
data = io.StringIO(string)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")  # Load df from the data string

for row in df.iterrows():
    print(f'The column id is {row[1]["id"]} and name {row[1]["name"]} have stock {row[1]["stock"]}')
```

We get this output:

```
The column id is 1 and name Fruit have stock 8
The column id is 2 and name Meet have stock 10
The column id is 3 and name Fish have stock 30
The column id is 4 and name Cake have stock 20
```